# COUNTIF showing inconsistent behavior

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I'm using the following formula to find a value in the 'CDS et al' spreadsheet:

=COUNTIF(A3,'CDS et al'!**A:A**)

It returns **0**, which is incorrect because I know the value shows up in the A column once. However, when I find the cell it's in manually and enter that into the countif formula, it finds it:

=COUNTIF(A3,'CDS et al'!**A2**)

The value is **1**. What gives? A2 is a subset of A:A! A:A should return 1 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are incorrect, COUNTIF has two arguments, range and criteria.  Your function has them the wrong way around.

Answer (score -1):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "CDS et al!")
```

For criteria parameter, you need to specify the text which will be used for comparison.

Comment: This is not the search text. It is the sheet name. With spaces in the sheet name, it needs to be enclosed in single quotes. After that follows the ! sign and after that the cell range. 'My Sheet'!A1

Comment: @teylyn: Oops. I am sorry for wrongly reading the question and hence the answer.